# Shiny observe()

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am having some trouble conceptualizing where I am erring with the `observe()` function in the below code:

```
observe({
  if (is.null(input$speciesSelect) | is.null(input$regionSelect))
  {
    output$height_summary_label <- renderUI(tags$b("Please select at least one species and at least one region"))
  } else
  {
    output$height_summary_label <- renderText("Height of selected corals (cm):")
    output$max_diam_summary_label <- renderText("Maximum diameter of selected corals (cm):")
    output$perp_diam_summary_label <- renderText("Perpendicular diameter of selected corals (cm):")
    output$depth_label <- renderText("Depth of selected corals (m):")

    output$height <- renderPrint(summary(summary_data()$HEIGHT))
    output$max_diam <- renderPrint(summary(summary_data()$MAX_DIAMETER))
    output$perp_diam <- renderPrint(summary(summary_data()$PERP_DIAMETER))
    output$depth <- renderPrint(summary(summary_data()$DEPTH))
    output$percent_disease <- renderPrint(paste("Disease present in", round((100 * nrow(subset(summary_data(), DISEASE == "present" | DISEASE == "P" | DISEASE == "p"))) / nrow(summary_data()), digits = 2) ,"percent of selected corals"))
    output$percent_bleach <- renderPrint(paste("Bleaching present in", round((100 * nrow(subset(summary_data(), BLEACH_CONDITION == "PL" | BLEACH_CONDITION == "P" | BLEACH_CONDITION == "T"))) / nrow(summary_data()), digits = 2), " percent of selected corals"))
  } 
})
```

The problem is, if I hit the button that displays the modal window with the stats immediately, it outputs the `"Please select..."` message, which is good. But if I click on a region and species in the `checkboxGroupInput` and then unclick them, and then open the modal, it displays `"Error: argument is of length zero"` for each output.

Comment: I would suggest googling for "r shiny devcon videos" and watch Joe Cheng's videos on reactivity to get a better understanding on how to use observe. You're not supposed to put all these render functions inside observe, you need to do some readings or watch videos to understand it better :)

Comment: Sure, but just this once can you give me a hint?

Comment: It's hard to tell without a minimal exmaple. `browser()` should help you debbug this.

Comment: Thanks, I think I fixed it